# Using MultipartEntityBuilder to upload files

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have some existing Java code to upload files (as byte arrays) to Box.net, and recently I thought it would be good to upgrade the code to Apache HttpClient 4.4. However, this has been proving a little harder than expected. Here is my working legacy code:

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
for (NameValuePair parameter : parameters) {
    String parameterName = parameter.getName();
    String parameterValue = parameter.getValue();
    StringBody valueBody = new StringBody(parameterValue, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);                    
    multipartEntity.addPart(parameterName, valueBody);
}

Iterator iterator = byteArrayHashMap.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayHashMap.get(key);
    multipartEntity.addPart(key, new ByteArrayBody(byteArray, key));
}

postMethod.setEntity(multipartEntity);
```

and here is the new code:

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
for (NameValuePair parameter : parameters) {
    String parameterName = parameter.getName();
    String parameterValue = parameter.getValue();
    StringBody valueBody = new StringBody(parameterValue, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);                    
    multipartEntityBuilder.addPart(parameterName, valueBody);
}

Iterator iterator = byteArrayHashMap.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayHashMap.get(key);
    multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(key, byteArray);
}

postMethod.setEntity(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
```

When I run the new code, the server complains of a missing parameter. Am I using the MultipartEntityBuilder correctly?

Comment: In case anyone stumbles across this question, I was able to solve this by updating the addBinaryBody call to set the ContentType as follows: multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(key, byteArray, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, key);

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this question, I was able to solve this by updating the addBinaryBody call to set the ContentType as follows: multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(key, byteArray, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, key);